# App crashing in completion handler with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Can anyone help me in fixing my API call function. I parse the data and store it in results and if there is any errors while parsing I throw a failure json error. If the parsing is successful then I save the data in Database.
But my app crashes at this line after json parsing fails

```
 return completion(.failure(.jsonError("Values of expenses not found")))
```

Here is my whole function:-

```
func loadExpenseOfReport(organizationID: Int, reportID: Int, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {

   self.remote.loadExpensesOfReport(organizationID, reportID: reportID) { result  in
       switch result {

       case .success(let json):
           var result : (json: [[String: Any]], ids: [Int])
           do {
               result = try Expense.processExpenses(JSON: json!, organizationID: Int(self.user.organization.organizationID))
           } catch let error {
               return completion(.failure(.jsonError("Values of expenses not found"))) // App crashes here
           }
           print("result \(result)")
           // Save in database
        self.dataStack.enqueueCoreDataBlock({ context in
               Sync.changes(result.json, inEntityNamed: "Expense", predicate: nil, parent: nil, parentRelationship: nil, inContext: context, operations: .all, completion: { error in
                   guard error == nil else {
                       return completion(.failure(.syncError(error!)))
                   }
                   return completion(.success(nil))
               })
           })
           //return completion(.success(nil))

       case .failure(let error):
           return completion(.failure(error))
       }
   }
```

But when I changes the above lines of saving in Database to this, it doesn't crashes anymore.

```
//self.dataStack.enqueueCoreDataBlock({ context in
           Sync.changes(result.json, inEntityNamed: "Expense", predicate: nil, parent: nil, parentRelationship: nil, inContext: self.dataStack.viewContext, operations: .all, completion: { error in
               guard error == nil else {
                   return completion(.failure(.syncError(error!)))
               }
               return completion(.success(nil))
           })
       //})
```

Comment: You should remove the `return` statement before calling `completion`. Your function is returning void, so you can't return anything, moreover the closure is "returned" when it's called by `completion(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @DávidPásztor, can you please help me out, I have edit the question a bit. I comment out the two lines and instead of saving it in context I save it in self.dataStack.viewContext and everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to 'return' a completion block. Just call it like this :

```
var result : (json: [[String: Any]], ids: [Int])
           do {
               result = try Expense.processExpenses(JSON: json!, organizationID: Int(self.user.organization.organizationID))
           } catch let error {
               completion(.failure(.jsonError("Values of expenses not found")))
           }
```